# How to prove that this simple graph does not exist?

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning

> Show that there is no simple graph with 6 vertices in which there are
>   5 vertices having following degrees 5,5,3,2,1

So, we have 5 vertices *(=odd number of vertices)* with an even number of degrees. Why? Because 5+5+3+2+1 = 16. We don't know the sixth one, so I do this:

`[5,5,3,2,1,n]` where *n = unknown*. We already know that the rest is 16 and I drew this graph, and I get a graph where one vertex is connected to another vertex twice *(so it has two edges between vertex x and y)*...

Now, I know that from the definition of a `simple graph`, that it is *impossible as a simple graph does not allows us to have two edges between two vertices*.

My question: am I correct and is this "enough" to "proof" this, or should I calculate something? I mean, could I even calculate this with `Havel-Hakimi` for example? If so, could someone **show** me that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose it's possible.  We have 6 vertices with these degrees:

[image]

Let's add the edges starting from the largest-degree vertices.  We pick one of the degree-5 vertices: since there are only 5 other vertices, it must be adjacent to all of them.

[image]

Now let's do the next degree-5 vertex.  It likewise must be adjacent to all other vertices.

[image]

A clash arises.  The degree-1 vertex has degree greater than 1, giving a contradiction.

---

The main observation is that:

- In an $n$-vertex simple graph, vertices of degree $n-1$ are adjacent to all other vertices.

So consequently:

- If we have $k$ vertices of degree $n-1$ in a $n$-vertex simple graph, every other vertex must have degree $k$ or more.

Comment: I love answers with an example. Thank you very much, Rebecca!

Answer (score 2):

You have two vertices $P_1$ and $P_2$ each adjacent to all other vertices.
You also have a third vertex $P_3$ of valency one. But $P_3$ is adjacent to $P_1$ and $P_2$. Ouch!

Comment: What does "valency" mean? It's essentially saying that same I did, I guess, but what I want to know if I can prove this with Havel Hakimi theorem?

Comment: @Siyah valency is degree. I don't know what the Havel-Hakimi theorem is :-)